# where does hadoop use yarn.log.file in java src code

Tags: hadoop

I see that when starting a NodeManager，
the -Dyarn.log.file=yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-hostname1.log parameter is passed to the NodeManager's main method,
but I can't find where this yarn.log.file is used in java code so that log message can write into the yarn.log.file

wish for some help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop uses `log4j` behind the scenes. `Log4j` supports different configurable appenders, but when the logging system is configured, you will not see any reference at the file that is just one of many possible appenders ( ie output for the log ). You will probably dig on various log4j configuration file in the hadoop sources looking for `*log4j.properties` and you will eventually find your referenced file.

Comment: java -Dkey=value myclass arg1 arg2 ,key=value will not be passed to main method,  but be added to system properties which can override the values defined in log4j.properties

Comment: at first, i think yarn.log.file been passed to nodemanager main method, now i see i am wrong.  also, thank you for answering my 1st question at stackoverflow timely